# [Error: Query.gameWeeks defined in resolvers, but not in schema]

Tags: mongodb, graphql, apollo

Been following a tutorial for building a GraphQL backend with Apollo + MongoDB, but I'm getting errors even though it is more or less identical to the tutorial(changed a bit for my own purpose). Code for tutorial can be found here: https://github.com/Zepsey/graphql-api-tutorial

YT for the Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VLVEkyQPguU&list=PLgghBnrtImuIdeDO9bosyEP-7DW0Uup2e&index=9&t=1s

Apologies for the drop of so much code, I've been looking at this for a few hours now, and I thought I found a possible solution in: [GraphQL : the object name is defined in resolvers, but not in schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49990427/graphql-the-object-name-is-defined-in-resolvers-but-not-in-schema) as it is a similar error to what I am experiencing.

But my files and code is structured differently, so I don't see how that solution would work out in my case.

```
node_modules/graphql-tools/dist/generate/addResolveFunctionsToSchema.js:79
                throw new _1.SchemaError(typeName + "." + fieldName + " defined in resolvers, but not in schema");
                ^

[Error: Query.gameWeeks defined in resolvers, but not in schema]
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

My Schema (/models/gameWeek.js):

```
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const GameWeekSchema = new Schema({
    player_id: {
        type: Number
    },
    player_name: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    points: {
        type: Number
    },
    rank: {
        type: Number
    },
    previous_rank: {
        type: Number
    },
    total: {
        type: Number
    },
    team_name: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    team_id: {
        type: Number
    }
})

const GameWeek = mongoose.model("GameWeek", GameWeekSchema)

module.exports = { GameWeek }
```

My queries(resolver/queries):

```
 module.exports = async (_, {}, {models}) => {
    // returns all gameweeks in DB
    return await models.GameWeek.find();
}
```

My index file in queries(/resolvers/queries/index.js):

```
const gameWeeks = require('./gameWeek');

module.exports = {
    gameWeeks
}
```

My types in (/types/gameWeek.js):

```
const { gql } = require('apollo-server');

const GameWeek = gql`
    type GameWeek{
        player_id: ID!
        player_name: String!
        points: Float
        rank: Int!
        previous_rank: Int!
        total: Float
        team_name: String!
        team_id: Int
    }
    type Query {
        GameWeeks: [GameWeek]!
    }
    input CreateGameWeek{
        player_id: ID!
        player_name: String!
        points: Float
        rank: Int!
        previous_rank: Int!
        total: Float
        team_name: String!
        team_id: Int
    }
    input UpdateGameWeek{
        player_id: ID!
        player_name: String
        points: Float
        rank: Int
        previous_rank: Int
        total: Float
        team_name: String
        team_id: Int
    }
    type DeleteGameWeek {
        player_id: ID!
    }
    type GameWeekUpdateResponse{
        success: Boolean!
        message: String
        gameweeks: [GameWeek]
    }
    
    type Mutation{
        createGameWeek(input: CreateGameWeek!): GameWeek!
        updateGameWeek(player_id: ID,input: UpdateGameWeek!): GameWeekUpdateResponse!
        deleteGameWeek(player_id: ID!): DeleteGameWeek!
    }
`;

module.exports = GameWeek;
```

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED:

Silliest and oldest mistake to any programmer, I had a typo in there.

in /types/gameWeek.js

Previous:

```
type Query {
        GameWeeks: [GameWeek]!
    }
```

Fixed:

```
type Query {
        GameWeek: [GameWeek]!
    }
```

Removed the s.